# A ">" character is showing up in the browser, but it's nowhere in the HTML or in the the Rails View

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

**How is this for weird...**

In the browser:

```
New Issue

>
Description:    Raised by:    Raised:
```

In Firebug:

```
<p class="normal">
    <a href="/issues/new">New Issue</a>
</p>
&gt;
<table class="show">
 <tr class="table-headings">
  <td>Description:</td>
  <td>Raised by:</td>
  <td>Raised:</td>

 </tr>
```

In the source HTML:

```
<p class="normal">
    <a href="/issues/new">New Issue</a>
</p>
<table class="show">
 <tr class="table-headings">
  <td>Description:</td>
  <td>Raised by:</td>
  <td>Raised:</td>
 </tr>
```

In the Rails view:

```
<p class="normal">
 <%= link_to 'New Issue', new_issue_path %>
</p>
<table class="show">
 <tr class="table-headings">
  <td>Description:</td>
  <td>Raised by:</td>
  <td>Raised:</td>
 </tr>
```

Where does the 'greater than' (>) character in Firebug and in the browser view come from? It's nowhere in my code!

Comment: When you do a view source in Firefox (CTRL+U), then it's /not/ there?  How about other browsers?  IE has the best view source because it doesn't re-request the HTML (e.g. the source from a POST is viewable).

Comment: Where are you getting the "source HTML" from? What does the HTML look like on the wire?

Comment: Any JS Code which might add this char, after the page loaded, this might be the reason rails + html seems okay, yet firebug tells different.

Comment: Source HTML is same for IE, Chrome and Firefox. Regarding JS, using jquery, but no code in application.js for that class or tag at all.

Comment: The only time I've seen discrepancies between HTML and the likes of Firebug is when there's some DOM manipulation going on with JavaScript.

Comment: There's not any CSS `content:'>'` or anything is there?  That would be unusual to appear in Firebug, but you may have a different version than me.

Comment: Is the '>' visible in all those browsers or just Firefox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere in your table you have an additional `>` - any content that is in a table but not inside a `<th>` or `<td>` generally gets hoisted up above the rest of the table content.

Paste the rest of the table HTML from a "View Source" (not from Firebug) and we'll help you spot it

Comment: This is probably going to be it.  Just replicated it myself.  Nice one!  (A HTML Validator will spot it for you)

Answer (score 0):

`&gt;` is the encoding of `>` in HTML. See [HTML special characters](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/html/special)